# Trace identity for spin matrices in supersymmetry

Tags: supersymmetry

My question comes from Srednicki chapter 95, specifically equation 95.75.

Srednicki gives an identity to evaluate the trace of his left-handed fermion matrices:

$$Tr(S^{\mu\nu}_LS^{\rho\sigma}_L)$$

He evaluates it using the identity:

$$Tr(S^{\mu\nu}_LS^{\rho\sigma}_L)=1/2[g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}-g^{\mu\sigma} g^{\nu\rho}-i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}]$$

I understand where the first two terms on the right hand side come from.  Using some identities and raising/lowering operators, I get the same.

I am not sure at the levi-civita term, however.  Why is that there?  It seems to be related to an earlier identity on the left-handed fermion matrices.